# How to paste vector elements comma-separated and in quotation marks?

Tags: r, string

I want to select columns of data frame `dfr` by their names in a certain order, that i obtain with the numbers in first place.

```
> (x <- names(dfr)[c(3, 4, 2, 1, 5)])
[1] "c" "d" "b" "a" "e"
```

In the final code there only should be included the names version, because it's safer.

```
dfr[, c("c", "d", "b", "a", "e")
```

I want to paste the elements separated with commas and quotation marks into a string, in order to include it into the final code. I've tried a few options, but they don't give me what I want:

```
> paste(x, collapse='", "')
[1] "c\", \"d\", \"b\", \"a\", \"e"
> paste(x, collapse="', '")
[1] "c', 'd', 'b', 'a', 'e"
```

I need something like `"'c', 'd', 'b', 'a', 'e'"`,—of course `"c", "d", "b", "a", "e"` would be much nicer.

***Data***

```
dfr <- setNames(data.frame(matrix(1:15, 3, 5)), letters[1:5])
```

Comment: I do not understand "In order to select columns by name à la dfr[, c("a", "b", "c")] I want to paste the elements separated with commas and quotation marks into a string." It simply doesn't make sense and I assume you have an XY problem.

Comment: just try `dfr[x]`.

Comment: Wait, I'm editing the question ....

Comment: Still doesn't make sense. There is simply no reason to create such a string for subsetting in R.

Comment: Are you looking for `dput(x)`?

Comment: @Roland Yes that's exactly what I needed, thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So `dput(x)` is the correct answer but just in case you were wondering how to achieve this by modifying your existing code you could do something like the following:

```
cat(paste0('c("', paste(x, collapse='", "'), '")'))
c("c", "d", "b", "a", "e")
```

Can also be done with packages (as Tung has showed), here is an example using `glue`:

```
library(glue)
glue('c("{v}")', v = glue_collapse(x, '", "'))
c("c", "d", "b", "a", "e")
```

Comment: Thanks for playing the `paste()` mess through to the end, very clever. I'll then prefer `dput()` though.^^

Answer (score 2):

Try `vector_paste()` function from the [`datapasta`](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/datapasta/vignettes/how-to-datapasta.html) package

```r
library(datapasta)

vector_paste(input_vector = letters[1:3])
#> c("a", "b", "c")

vector_paste_vertical(input_vector = letters[1:3]) 
#> c("a",
#>   "b",
#>   "c")
```

Answer (score 1):

Or, using base R, this gives you what you want:

```
(x <- letters[1:3])
q <- "\""
( y <- paste0("c(", paste(paste0(q, x, q), collapse = ", ") , ")" ))
[1] "c(\"a\", \"b\", \"c\")"
```

Though I'm not realy sure why you want it? Surely you can simply subset like this:

```
df <- data.frame(a=1:3, b = 1:3, c = 1:3)
df[ , x]

  a b c
1 1 1 1
2 2 2 2
3 3 3 3

df[ , rev(x)]

  c b a
1 1 1 1
2 2 2 2
3 3 3 3
```

Answer (score 0):

suppose you want to add a quotation  infront and at the end of a text, and save it as an R object -  use the `capture.output` function from `utils` pkg.

Example. I want ABCDEFG  to be saved as an R object as "ABCDEFG"

```
> cat("ABCDEFG")  
>     ABCDEFG
> cat("\"ABCDEFG\"")
>     "ABCDEFG"
>
```

#To save output of the cat as an R object including the quotation marks at the start and end of the word use the capture.ouput

```
> add_quote <- capture.output(cat("\"ABCDEFG\""))
> add_quote
    [1] "\"ABCDEFG\""
```